# arp spoffing ip forwarding using scapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy, arp

I building an build arp spoofing attack using scapy. I allready manged to get the attack work with linux ip forwarding.

```
os.system("echo %s > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" % (f,))
```

But I want to be able to modify the packges on the fly and send edited packges, therfore I need to reimplment the ip forwarding. I tried doing this using this code, but the other computer/ gateaway dosent get the packges though they apper in the attacker.

```
#gIP is the gatwaway ip
#arp t able is an arptable I gatherd before I started the attack
#both of them have the correct value so the problem dosent lay there
def pkt_handler(self, pkt):
        pkt.show()
        ip = pkt.getlayer(sp.IP)
        get_mac = lambda x: info.arp_table.get(x, info.arp_table[info.gIP])
        ether = sp.Ether(dst=get_mac(ip.dst))
        sp.sendp(ether/ip)
```

edit:
After a lot of debugging and looking at a tcpdump I think I know what causes the problam. If there is  client A and server B and attacker S. when client A sends to server B lets say an echo messege. the server gets the messege and respondes to it by sending to the attacker but somehow scapy cant sniff the messege even though tcpdump can. No idea what casues this problam any help will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

for ip forward or arp spoof use alerady known tools for that

```
arpspoof client server
arpspoof server client
```

or use EtterCAP

Comment: I know but I try to implment them myself. About the ip forward if I use the kernal ip forwarding I cant temper/ change packges so it wont work.